# How to differentiate items in an appended list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I have a for loop that operates on several different data sources. I created an empty list to append within the for loop for specific calculations that are done. This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to differentiate the values in some way so that I can quickly determine from which data source the value in the appended list matches to? Here's a snippet of my code for example:

```
mean_list = []
mode_list = []
median_list = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    df_mean = df['price'].mean()
    df_mode = df['price'].mode()
    df_median = df['price'].median()

    mean_list.append(df_mean)
    mode_list.append(df_mode)
    median_list.append(df_median)
```

From here, I'm not sure where to go in order to make it easy to differentiate between all the different files that I'm looping through. If it was only a handful, I wouldn't worry about it too much, but the `all_files` variable created using the glob package (which is not shown in this code snippet) has over 100 files that are in it, so it'd be nice to have an easier way to match the values found in the for loop and appended to the lists to their files looped through. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about making a dataframe with columns `filename`, `mean`, `mode`, `median`, instead of separate lists for each?

Comment: That would be easier. I've created the empty dataframe, but how exactly do I append it getting the filename and values into it? Something like ```df_values.append(filename,mean,mode,median)``` ?

Comment: `append()` is deprecated, use [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)